# Which chapter of the manga does Season 3 of Nanatsu No Taizai anime start?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

If I want to start reading the manga of Nanatsu no Taizai by the chapter season 3 of the anime start (so I avoid most things which were already shown in the anime), which chapter should I start reading the manga?

Answer (score 1):

That should be volume 25 of the manga.

I just checked it here;
https://nanatsu-no-taizai.fandom.com/wiki/Story_Arcs